# UIScrollView size on changing orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to handle a change in device orientation for a paged `UIScrollView`. My problem is I need to get its size in the new orientation but I'm not sure how.

In my example the `UIScrollView` is sandwiched between a `UINavigationBar` and a `UIPageControl`.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm assuming my options are `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` and `willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:` but I can't figure out where to get the size.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any screenshot would be useful.

Comment: this sounds like a UICollectionView with a collection view flow layout.

Comment: what do you mean by **it's size**?

Comment: @AndréSlotta I mean it's bounds. I can use the View to get it's width but I'm unsure how to get the height since the navbar height is different in landscape for example

Answer (score 0):

what about...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    print(scrollView.frame)
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it might work but I just tested it and it get's called 3 times in my example. Any way to test for which subview is being layed out?

Comment: no. unfortunately i don't think so. what are you planning to do after getting the scrollview's new size?

Comment: I need to set the scrollview content size and redraw the visible page, it's predecessor and it's successor so that they fit the new size. I might be going about this the wrong way though!